# XSLT with DROP down

Tags: asp.net, xslt

Below xslt am using for binding the value to drop down, but the value is there in the "Value" attribute still in the selected value always showing as "Select".

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Fields/Field[@id='State']">  

            <select req="{./@req}" name="leaveform" misstext="Please Select" fieldid="{./@id}" id="txt{./@id}" style="width:100px;" boundProp="value" >
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@fieldValue" /> 
    </xsl:attribute>
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">
         <!--<xsl:if test="GA">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute> 
        </xsl:if>-->
        Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>

        </select>       
           </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet is creating a `value` attribute for the `select` element, which is not correct in HTML.

What you need to create is probably something like this, with the attribute `selected="selected"` for the option having the current value of the field:

**Output**

```
<select req="reqvalue" name="leaveform" misstext="Please Select" fieldid="State" id="txtState" style="width:100px;" boundProp="value">
   <option value="">--Select--</option>
   <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
   <option value="AK" selected="selected">Alaska</option>
   <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
   ...
</select>
```

So, from your XSLT we can suppose your input contains something like this:

**Input**

```
...
<Fields>
    <Field id="State" req="reqvalue" fieldValue="KS"/>
</Fields>
...
```

If you can use only XSLT 1.0, you need an xml file with the different options:

**select.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<select>
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    ....
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
</select>
```

And this is the stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Field[@id='State']">
        <!-- get the current value of the field -->
        <xsl:variable name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@fieldValue" /> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- get the different options -->
        <xsl:variable name="states" select="document('select.xml')"/>
        <!-- build the result -->
        <select req="{@req}" name="leaveform" misstext="Please Select" fieldid="{@id}" id="txt{@id}" style="width:100px;" boundProp="value" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$states//option">
                <xsl:with-param name="selectedValue" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </select>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xsl:param name="selectedValue"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@value"/>
            <!-- add the selected attribute to the option 
                with the current value -->
            <xsl:if test="@value = $selectedValue">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Single-file variant**

If you can use XSLT 2.0, or your XSLT 1.0 processor supports the `document('')` function call returning the stylesheet tree, instead of using an external xml file you can have the different `option` elements directly inside a variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- variable with the different options -->
    <xsl:variable name="options">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="Field[@id='State']">
        <!-- get the current value of the field -->
        <xsl:variable name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@fieldValue" /> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <!-- build the result -->
        <select req="{@req}" name="leaveform" misstext="Please Select" fieldid="{@id}" id="txt{@id}" style="width:100px;" boundProp="value" >
            <!-- with XSLT 2.0 you can select simply "$options/option" -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'options']/option">
                <xsl:with-param name="selectedValue" select="$value"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </select>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="option">
        <xsl:param name="selectedValue"/>
        <option value="{@value}">
            <!-- add the selected attribute to the option 
                with the current value -->
            <xsl:if test="@value = $selectedValue">
                <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </option>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If OP is using an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports `node-set()` or even `document('')` (with an empty string), they don't need an external file for the options.